# On the success of the function change the color of the td

Tags: javascript

In the table's td, I have a ternary conditional operation, which will define whether the td is bold or normal, as shown below:

```
tbody.append( $('') .append($(`<td class="td-info table__content" data-heading="Assunto" data-alerta="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }" onclick="marld();" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][2])) )
```

If the td is in bold and if the user clicks on the line I want it to be the normal color without updating the table.

For this I am trying this way:

```
function marld(){
    var ite_id = []; //arraypara armazenar os id's a serem deletados
    
    $(".colorir").each(function(){ //percorre todos os tr que possui a classe colorir
     ite_id.push($(this).find(".td-info").attr("data-alerta")); //adiciona o id da linha ao array
    })

    $.ajax({
        url: './marcaler',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {ite_id:ite_id},
        error: function(){

        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
          var self = this;
            if(result != ''){
                $(self).css("font-weight", "normal")
            }
        
        }
    });      
}
```

If you do `console.log (result);` clicking will return `"1"`.

If you do `console.log (self);` clicking on returns `{url: "./marcaler", type: "POST", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true, ...}` but does not change the color of the bold to normal.

tbody complete:

```
  tbody.append(
        $('<tr class="table__row">')
            .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="De" onclick="marld();" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][1]))
            .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Tipo" onclick="marld();" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][8]))
            .append($(`<td class="td-info table__content" data-heading="Assunto" data-alerta="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }" onclick="marld();" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][2]))
            .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Conteúdo" onclick="marld();" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][3]))
            .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Estado" onclick="marld();" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][4]))
            .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Recebido" onclick="marld();" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][5]))
    )
```

Comment: The `var self = this;` is pointless where you put it, because you're already inside the function. You need to move that outside the new context.

Comment: Move this line : `var self = this;` to the outer scope. (below `var ite_id = []`) line.

Comment: In the `success` callback, what is it you're trying to change the CSS of?

Comment: @FZs It was when copying, but in my code I have how I updated the question

Comment: @Chris G If you move to before ajax, the console returns: `Window console {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window,…}`

Comment: @Eldar If you put the self in the console there it returns: `Window console {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window,…}`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I am trying to change the td css, if it is in bold it changes to normal

Comment: My guess is you need to move the `$.ajax` call inside the click handler, that way you can refer to the clicked `<td>` using `self` if you store it before the `$.ajax` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your updated question, this looks a **lot** like a use-case for event delegation, if you're putting the same handler (`marld`) on every `td` in the table. (Or on every `td.td-info` in the table, etc.)

In that case, remove the `onclick="marld()"` from the `td`s and use a single handler on the `tbody`, like this:

```
tbody.on("click", "td", marld);
```

or if they all have `td-info`, be more precise:

```
tbody.on("click", "td.td-info", marld);
```

jQuery will respond to clicks that bubble to the `tbody` from its contents by checking to see if the click passed through a `td`/`td.td-info` and, if so, calling `marld` with `this` set to the `td` that the click passed through.

But if you don't want to use event delegation, readon.

---

Instead of using an old-style `onxyz`-attribute event handler, create the `td` and use modern event handling to hook up the `marld` function; there's also no reason for the `$('').append(...)`:

```
const td = $(`<td class="td-info table__content" data-heading="Assunto" data-alerta="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`);
td.append(data[i][2]);
td.on("click", marld);
tbody.append(td);
```

Then, in `marld` `this` will refer to that `td`, so use that in your success handler. To make sure `this` isn't set by the caller, use an arrow function, not a traditional function:

```
function marld(){
    var ite_id = []; //arraypara armazenar os id's a serem deletados
    
    $(".colorir").each(function(){ //percorre todos os tr que possui a classe colorir
     ite_id.push($(this).find(".td-info").attr("data-alerta")); //adiciona o id da linha ao array
    })

    $.ajax({
        url: './marcaler',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {ite_id:ite_id},
        error: function(){

        },
        success: (result) => // *** Arrow function
        { 
            if(result != ''){
                $(this).css("font-weight", "normal") // *** Use `this`
            }
        }
    });      
}
```

---

Re your updated question, you'd hook up `marld` to those multiple `td`s by just calling `.on` on them after appending everything, like this:

```
tbody.append(
    $('<tr class="table__row">')
        .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="De" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][1]).on("click", mar1ld))
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Tipo" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][8]).on("click", mar1ld))
        .append($(`<td class="td-info table__content" data-heading="Assunto" data-alerta="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][2]).on("click", mar1ld))
        .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Conteúdo" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][3]).on("click", mar1ld))
        .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Estado" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][4]).on("click", mar1ld))
        .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Recebido" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).append(data[i][5]).on("click", mar1ld))
)
```

Comment: My code is this, it simply has 5 more td, but I think I can still apply this example

Comment: As in addition to this td I have five more tds, can you put an example with two tds to understand this solution?

Comment: @Junior - You just use the same code for all the `td`s. When the handler is called, `this` will refer to the specific `td` that was clicked.

Comment: Yes I understood that, the problem is to set up the tbody. I will comment here all my append tbody

Comment: I attached the complete tbody to the question. I call the marld function in all tds to do this action click on the column that click on the row. 
The problem is how I assemble the tbody complete with the solution it presented

Comment: @Junior - Actually, looking at your updated question, I'd use event delegation; see the updated answer for details.

Comment: @Junior - But I've also updated the end with how you'd do it if you don't want to use event delegation.

Comment: I understood the objective and the idea. I was in doubt where to apply this line in my code: `tbody.on("click", "td.td-info", marld);`. Do I replace this one? `tbody.append(`

Comment: @Junior - You don't *replace* it, no. You still want to append the `td`s to the `tbody`. You'd just add it (either before or after, doesn't matter).

Comment: ok, i implemented your solution, but do not change the color of the td when clicking.

Comment: @Junior - Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: I will explain the reason for not changing the color in your solution. Because with its solution the marld function does not insert the information of having clicked on the line in the database and no longer returns 1

Comment: @Junior - Nothing in what I suggested would change whether `marld` inserts the information in the database.